# How to extract the node and cell data values in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have just started using GIS applications so i am a novice in this field. I am currently using QGIS. The project demands the unstructured(triangular) meshing which i was able to achieve through QGIS-GMSH plugin. Now I have it meshed and next I want is to extract the node(x, y coordinates of all nodes) and cell data(nodes comprising the triangular cell and its coordinates) values and that's where i am stuck. I googled it but no luck.

I hope I have used the right terminology and pardon me for any mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The **MMQGIS** plugin has a tool called `Geometry Export to CSV File` which allows you to extract both the nodes of your layer and its attributes data in two separate csv files:

[image: Export geometry to csv]

You can then add these csv files back into QGIS from the menubar:

```
Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer...
```

Add the geometric csv file as **point coordinates** by specifying the XY coordinates; add the attribute csv file as **no geometry (attribute only table)**:

[image: Add layer]

Both layers will have also contained a `"shapeid"` field. You can use this to **join** the attribute table to the points layer by right-clicking the add points layer and going to the **Joins** tab:

[image: Joins]

Comment: i did that which gave me the coordinates for the nodes but it didn't provide any data for the cells

Comment: @AkshayPandit - When you ran the `Export Geometry to CSV` tool, could you specify two output paths: one for geometry, the other for attribute data?

Comment: Yes, I can..i get two .csv files generated. In "attributes" file,i get the shapeid and FID columns and in the "nodes" file, i get the x-y coordinates of the nodes but for each shapeid i get three different x-y coordinates.